# Find $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to find $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}}$ using Stirling formula $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi} n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}$ as $n \to \infty$.
Using the formula, I manage to guess that the limit is $0$. However, I am note quite sure how to rigorously show it.

In particular, I know that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!} \cdot \frac{(3n)^{3n+1/2}e^{-3n}}{n^{3n+3/2}e^{-3n}}=
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!}{(3n)!} \cdot \frac{3^{3n+1/2}}{n}
=1.$$
from Stirling formula. But is it valid to the $n$th square root of the limit in this situation?

Generally, if $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)=1$, is it true that 
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{f(n)}=1$?

Comment: Yes: $1^0 = 1$ is not an indeterminate form.  So if $f(n) \to 1$ and $1/n \to 0$ we may conclude $f(n)^{1/n} \to 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(n) \to 1$ then $\log(f(n)) \to 0$ so $\frac 1 n \log(f(n)) \to 0$. Hence $e^{\frac 1 n \log(f(n)) } \to 1$ and $(f(n))^{1/n} \to 1$.

Comment: This may be pedantic but I believe $f(n)$ has to approach $1$ fast enough to not be overtaken by the $1/n$ factor,   So not necessarily true for every $f$ ?

Comment: Please read the proof carefully and tell me if you find a mistake in any step. The rate at which $f(n) \to 1$ does not matter. @DanielV

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Note that $\min{(f(n),1)}\leq \sqrt[n]{f(n)}\leq\max{(f(n),1)}$ if $f(n)>0$ and $n\in \mathbb N_+$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{I shall show  }\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{(n!)^m}{mn!}}=\dfrac1{m^m}\text{ where }m\text{ is a positive integer}$$

$$A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{r=1}^n\dfrac r{n+r}\cdot\prod_{r=1}^n\dfrac r{2n+r}\cdots\prod_{r=1}^n\dfrac r{(m-1)n+r}\right)^{1/n}$$

$$\ln A=\sum_{p=1}^{m-1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\ln\left(\dfrac{\dfrac rn}{p+\dfrac rn}\right) $$

$$\ln A=\sum_{p=1}^{m-1}\int_0^1\ln\dfrac x{p+x}dx=\sum_{p=1}^{m-1}(p\ln p-(p+1)\ln(p+1))$$

So, $\ln A$ [telescopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) to $=1\ln1-m\ln m=\ln\dfrac1{m^m}$